# Visual Studio Version Compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I coded a windows desktop application about 5 years ago with "Visual Basic 2010 - Express Edition". Now, i want to make some upgrades on my program. I have VB2010 Express Edition on my computer. But i want to uninstall VB2010 Express Edition and install "Visual Studio 2017" instead of it. But I am not sure if i can run my codes on "Visual Studio 2017" or not. You may say: "try it and if can't run your code turn back to VB2010". But I am not sure if i can turn back to earlier version after installing the 2017 version.

Comment: As long as you are not sure then *don't* uninstall that Express edition.  Then make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't install Visual Studio 2017 and try running your code. If it works, you can then uninstall VB2010 and you are good to go. If you are worried about making changes to the code/project to get it to work in VS2017, then just make a copy of the project first and keep the original as a back up.

Comment: Or run VS2017 in a VM. Or in the worst case, format your machine and install Visual Studio 2010 afresh.

Comment: Formatting the machine seems a little extreme doesn't it :)